# How to Bound this Lipschitz Continuous Functions?

Tags: derivatives, upper-lower-bounds, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a Lipschitz Continuous Function with parameter $L$. Now, we define two variables $x\in [\underline{x},\bar{x}]$ and $y$ and $z=(x,y)$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|y\|_2 \le S$.The function $g$ is defined as $g(z)=xf(z^\top \gamma)$ where $\gamma$ is a known vector of parameters. I am wondering if $g$ will be a Lipschitz Continuous Function, and what its coefficient is. How is it possible to write inequality related to the Lipschitz constant?
Thanks

Comment: So you're given $\underline{x},\overline{x},\gamma$ and you want to know if $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz? What have you tried already?

Comment: I think $g$ is a Lipschitz function, too, with constant $\bar{x}L+1$. Am I right? I don't know what I should write on the right hand side of the formula $|x_1 f(z_1^\top \gamma)  - x_2 f(z_2^\top \gamma) |\le (1+\bar{x}L)$.